# How to build a OCR for reading text from image?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, ocr, text-generation

This is my first time working on a OCR application. I have lot of scanned images of English text-book pages like [`this`](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/Book_of_Abraham_FirstPage.png) and I want to build a OCR using DL to `extract the text from each image`.

> Can anyone outline just the approach I need to take to implement it?

There are few questions that I couldn't figure out:

1) How do I need to do it? I mean I don't have any target label (or) annotations 
   (or) bounding box. 
2) What will be my target label be here? Do I need target label?

3) Is it possible to do un-supervised learning. If so How?

4) What are CRNN algorithms I need to check out to implement it?

Not looking for any api's (or) libraries (like teserract, vision-api etc..).

Comment: I don‘t understand what your question is. What do you want to predict? Please elaborate

Comment: @Peter Sorry for the confusion. I've cleaned up the question. I hope you can understand it now.